# Ionic app on iOS closed unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I have deployed an ionic app on my iPhone from a Xcode project. After 2 weeks, I tried to open my app on iPhone and it closed unexpectedly. Thus, today I have re-deployed the app, it can be opened successfully. However, I'm curious what is the cause and will it close unexpectedly again. Any suggestion? Thanks! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it happens again!. My app closes immediately after I open it. It's about 1 week since I re-deployed the app. Thus, I guess Apple dev (Personal team) allows me to  try it for a week. Maybe I need to register something.

Comment: did you manage to solve the problem? the exact same thing is happening for me, even without any webservices or requests.
it works perfectly fine for like a week and then suddenly stops working, and is only working after a redeploy

Comment: @NicolasGehlert I found that it is because we use free Apple developer account. The app can run only 7 days. If you want the app to run for a long period, you need to register an paid account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is just because I use a free Apple developer account. The app can run only about 7 days. If you want a long term app, you need to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be with the time that cordova takes to load. If your app is heavily loaded with javascript libraries, more controllers and factories, some external javascript files(from web) cordova takes a little more time to load, if it crosses the time that it has to, the app will be closed unexpectedly.

Same way in Android, you will see the error "{AppName} stopped unfortunately".

Comment: Alright, but I am confused why my app is available for a period and then becomes unavailable after a week. (When I open the app, it loads something for a second and then closes immediately) My app that I have re-deployed can be opened successfully without changing any code or structure. So, I still concern that it can be unavailable again after a period. Sorry if my question and comment are not clear.

Comment: May be you are calling some webservices on app launch and those webservices are not responding at that moment.